# How to write the script to implement the below logic?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

I am learning **bash scripting**, and I was trying to write a script to solve a problem but couldn't.

**Sample testcase :**

> **Input**:

```
StoreId,Name,Type,Revenue,StoreExpenses (this line is not provided as cmd line argument)

1,RockDeptStore,stationary,100,50
2,WembleyStore,departmental,85,81
3,HealthyStore,grocery,95,97
4,Ministore,medical,60,55
```

> **Output**:

```
1|RockDeptStore|stationary|100|50|50
4|Ministore|medical|60|55|5
2|WembleyStore|departmental|85|81|4
```

> **script.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

#inputs
for record in "$@"
do
revenue=$(cut -d ',' -f 4 <<< $record)
expenses=$(cut -d ',' -f 5 <<< $record)
((profit=revenue-expenses))
if [[ profit -gt 0 ]]
then
     # how to update this record with '|' and where to store this record so that I can access it later in my script for sorting.
fi
done
```

I need to write a shell-script `script.sh`, which takes input of each **store details** as **command line arguments**.

I need to print all the stores with an **additional field** `profit = Revenue - StoreExpenses` and need to change separator from ',' to '|'.

And print only those stores which have `profit > 0` in **decreasing order** of their respective `profit`, as given in sample **output** above.

We are running `script.sh` as:

```
./script.sh 1,RockDeptStore,stationary,100,50 2,WembleyStore,departmental,85,81 3,HealthyStore,grocery,95,97 4,Ministore,medical,60,55
```

Comment: "was trying to write a script". Please show your attempt, describe what problems you have with it and ask a specific question that will help you progress your attempt. Don't just ask for the whole code.

Comment: Okay, I have included the script  `script.sh` which I was writing, but got stuck in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string substitution to replace all the commas in each line

The pattern is: `${parameter//pattern/string}`
see Substring Replacement [at this link](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

So in your case, `${record//,/|}`

Then, you can save each iteration with profit > 0 to a variable, adding the profit column on the end. You can use the same variable and append a newline each time.

Finally, `sort` the lines.

The `-r` option reverses the sort.
The `-t` and `-k` option work together to look for the sixth item on each line, where the items are separated by `|`, and sort accordingly.

So all up it might look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

result=''
newline=$'\n'

#inputs
for record in "$@"
do

  revenue=$(cut -d ',' -f 4 <<< $record)
  expenses=$(cut -d ',' -f 5 <<< $record)
  ((profit=revenue-expenses))

  if [[ profit -gt 0 ]]
  then
    newRecord=${record//,/|}
    result+="${newRecord}|${profit}${newline}"
  fi
done

sorted=$(sort -rt'|' -k6 <<< ${result})

printf "${sorted}"
```

I had to make some additional changes to your script to make it work for me:

- `gt` -> `-gt`
- added `<<< ${record}` to the cut commands

Comment: @William_Mizzi. you used 'here strings' to provide stdin to cut and sort command, do we have any alternative to that?

Comment: why do we have to include `$` in `newline=$'\n'`?

Comment: You used 'here strings' to provide stdin to cut and sort command, do we have any alternative to that and why do we have to include `$` in `newline=$'\n'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sort` utility to sort the output.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for element; do
  IFS=, read -r _ _ _ revenue store_expenses <<< "$element"
  profit=$(( revenue - store_expenses ))
  if (( profit > 0 )); then
    output=${element//,/|}
    printf '%s|%s\n' "$output" "$profit"
  fi
done | sort -rt'|' -k 6
```

---

You can run the script with the arguments.

```sh
./script.sh 1,RockDeptStore,stationary,100,50 2,WembleyStore,departmental,85,81 3,HealthyStore,grocery,95,97 4,Ministore,medical,60,55
```